# String to Double in Java

Tags: java

I have in my Java app double numbers. I need to convert String to Double, but string representation of number is

> , - separates decimal part of number (
>   example    1,5  eq 6/4 )
>
> . - separates groups of three digits (
>   example  1.000.000  eq 1000000 )

.
How to achieve this conversion String to Double ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way of solving it using `DecimalFormat` without worrying about locales.

```
import java.text.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {

        DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
        dfs.setGroupingSeparator('.');
        dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');

        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        df.setGroupingSize(3);

        String[] tests = { "15,151.11", "-7,21.3", "8.8" };
        for (String test : tests)
            System.out.printf("\"%s\" -> %f%n", test, df.parseObject(test));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
"15,151.11" -> 15151.110000
"-7,21.3" -> -721.300000
"8.8" -> 8.800000
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like the German locale has that number format.

```
Double d = (Double) NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN).parse(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the parse method in DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get rid of the `,` and replace `,` with `.`:

```
String s = "1000.000,15";
double d = Double.valueOf(s.replaceAll("\\.", "").replaceAll("\\,", "."));   
System.out.print(d);
```

Answer (score -1):

`DecimalFormat` is your friend.

Comment: right but do not forget that you have to use right locale. Otherwise it will not work correctly.

Comment: could you provide a link for that class?

Comment: @mlkhmm do you mean DecimalFormat?